# Is that possible to have images, CSS and scripts in a Zend Framework module?

Tags: zend-framework

In my Zend Framework modules, I have views that require specific javascript, CSS and images.

Is that possible to include them in the module in a way that I don't have to copy them in each project that uses the module ? (because the "public/" folder is not part of the module, but specific to each application)

If not, how can I do ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

"Install Directions" that include linking/alaising "public_html/mymodule/" to a sub directory in your module folder is about the simplest it gets.

I have written a controller/action/route that serves up scripts/css/images in the past.  It wasn't terribly complicated, but it was kind of a pain to handle caching properly.  I'm not saying this is a *great* way to do it, I mean, you really shouldn't want to spend all the time setting up zend framework and dispatching an action to give someone a static javascript file...  However, you could do this **AND** tell them to link the directory too.

In case you decide to use it, here's the Abstract I wrote that can serve up some static content:

```
<?php

class MW_Script_Controller_Abstract extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
  protected $_basepath;

  public function publicAction()
  {
    // not initialized
    if (!$this->_basepath) throw new Exception("base path not set");


    if (!($filename = $this->_request->getParam("filename")))
      $filename = $this->_request->getParam(1);

    if (!$filename) throw new Exception("Unknown Filename");

    $fn = realpath($this->_basepath."/".$filename);

    if (!$fn || !is_file($fn)) throw new MW_Controller_404Exception("File not found");

    // determine extension to determine mime-type
    preg_match("#\.([^.]+)$#", $filename, $matches);
    if (!empty($matches[1]) switch (strtolower($matches[1]))
    {
      case "js": 
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/javascript'); 
        ini_set('html_errors', 0);
        break;
      case "css": 
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/css'); 
        ini_set('html_errors', 0);
        break;
      case "html":
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        break;
      default:
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain'); 
        ini_set('html_errors', 0);
        break;
    }

    // Disable Layout
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);     
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

    $mtime = filemtime($fn);

    if ($modsince = $this->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'))
    {
      $modsince = new Zend_Date($modsince);
      $modsince = $modsince->getTimestamp();

      if ($mtime <= $modsince) {
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(304); 
        return;
      }
    }

    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Last-Modified', gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s",$mtime). " GMT");
    readfile($fn);
    // All Done
  }
}
```

And the Route:

```
<?php
class MW_Script_Route extends Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Abstract
{
  /**
   * The Root Path for this "MW_Script_Controller" area
   *
   * @var string a root "path" for this route
   **/
  protected $_rootpath;

  /**
   * Holds user submitted default values for route's variables. Name and value pairs.
   * @var array
   */
  protected $_defaults = array();

  /**
   * Instantiates route based on passed Zend_Config structure
   *
   * @param Zend_Config $config Configuration object
   */
  public static function getInstance(Zend_Config $config)
  {
      $defs = ($config->defaults instanceof Zend_Config) ? $config->defaults->toArray() : array();
      return new self($config->route, $defs);
  }
  /**
   * Stores the basepath for later matching, also stores defaults.  If no "module" is passed in to 
   * the $defaults array,  the "basepath" will be used as a module name, "index" will be used as a 
   * controller, and "public" will be used as a action.
   *
   * @param string $route Map used to match with later submitted URL path
   * @param array $defaults Defaults for map variables with keys as variable names
   * @param array $reqs Regular expression requirements for variables (keys as variable names)
   */
  public function __construct($route, $defaults = array())
  {

      $route = trim($route, '/');
      $this->_defaults = (array) $defaults;
      if (!isset($this->_defaults["module"])) $this->_defaults["module"] = $route;
      if (!isset($this->_defaults["controller"])) $this->_defaults["controller"] = "index";
      if (!isset($this->_defaults["action"])) $this->_defaults["action"] = "public";

      $this->_rootpath = $route;

  }

  public function match($request)
  {
    $path = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
    if (substr($path, 0, strlen($this->_rootpath)) == $this->_rootpath)
    {
      $values = $this->_defaults;
      $values["filename"] = substr($path,strlen($this->_rootpath)+1);
      return $values;
    }
  }

  public function assemble($data = array(), $reset = false, $encode = false)
  {
    if (isset($data["filename"])) $filename = $data["filename"];
    if (isset($data["1"])) $filename = $data["1"];
    return $this->_rootpath . "/" .$filename;
  }

} // END class MW_Script_Controller_Route extends Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Abstract
```

Comment: Linking/aliasing : we (a team) work on Mac, Linux and Windows, and synchronise through SVN. I think this will be a real mess (and linking is not possible on windows). As fos the controller that serves the images, the theory is interesting, but I don't want to build up a whole Zend Application in memory just for a static image.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to put assets in `public` directory and use `baseUrl()` helper.

However, the best way is to move all scripts to `/public` directory. Then you will swapable 'skins'.
Of course, you'll have to add additional rules to `.htaccess` protect the `.phtml`'s

To do this, you will have to customize standard application structure to suit you needs.
For further explanation see [my answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450497/how-to-move-the-views-of-zend-layout/2450709#2450709).

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you : I have my module X that uses the image X1.jpg (this image is only used by X). If in another application, I use the X module, I don't want to copy the images (I want the images of module X inside the module). I don't see how your answer can help me.

Comment: Mmmh I have a doubt : when I talk about a script, I mean Javascript. You talk about ".phtml", this means views.